# How to replace / rename rows given some pattern in string?

Tags: r

I would like to convert some links corresponding to unique userID:

```
    df<- data.frame(

      employeeId = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
      linkToEmployee = c("http://intranet.homepageEmploye.com/herSalary",
                       "http://intranet.homepageEmploye.org/herSalary/Details",
                       "http://local.com/qa/for",
                       "here the homepage is missing",
                       "http://local.org/",
                       "here the homepage is missing"))


         employeeId                       linkToEmployee

    1          1         http://intranet.homepageEmploye.com/herSalary
    2          2 http://intranet.homepageEmploye.org/herSalary/Details
    3          3                               http://local.com/qa/for
    4          4                          here the homepage is missing
    5          5                                     http://local.org/
    6          6                          here the homepage is missing
```

Now I would like convert those links to that form:

```
    desired<- data.frame(

        employeeId = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
        linkToEmployee = c("intranet.com",
                           "intranet.org",
                           "local.com",
                           "here",
                           "local.org",
                           "here"))


            employeeId linkToEmployee

      1          1   intranet.com
      2          2   intranet.org
      3          3      local.com
      4          4           here
      5          5      local.org
      6          6           here
```

I have tried to use `gsub` for the case of intranet but that doesnt seem to work as expected.

```
    df$linkToEmployee <- gsub("http://intranet.homepageEmploye.com/", "intranet.com.", df$linkToEmployee)
```

However that doesnt work as expected

Comment: The special characters : . and / will be messing up your gsub.  It should work if you add the option `fixed=TRUE` to stop it interpreting it as a regex string.

Comment: What *exactly* is your desired result? Your example doesn’t really make this clear, as it doesn’t generalise. At any rate you should probably use a proper URI parser rather than an ad-hoc regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the package `urltools` which has some very useful functions for URL parsing. First you need to find out which are indeed URLs. To do this I searched for strings containing TLD.

```
library(urltools)

ind <- !is.na(suffix_extract(domain(df$linkToEmployee))$suffix)

df$linkToEmployee[ind] <- sapply(strsplit(domain(df$linkToEmployee[ind]), '\\.|\\s+'), 
                                      function(i) paste(head(i, 1), tail(i, 1), sep = '.'))

df$linkToEmployee[!ind] <- gsub('\\s+.*', '', df$linkToEmployee[!ind])

df
#  employeeId linkToEmployee
#1          1   intranet.com
#2          2   intranet.org
#3          3      local.com
#4          4           here
#5          5      local.org
#6          6           here
```

**NOTE**

Make sure that your URL variable is not factor. Either read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or do

```
df$linkToEmployee <- as.character(df$linkToEmployee)
```